# f:ajax onevent doesn't work with predefined function, but works with inline function

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a `<h:commandButton>` which submits a form by `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:commandButton  value="Create Project" styleClass="greyishBtn submitForm">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{projectController.create}" 
        render=":tblProject" />
</h:commandButton>
```

It works as it should be, but when I tried to add `onevent` attribute like:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{projectController.create}"
    onevent="createProjectEventHandler" render=":tblProject" />
```

with this JavaScript that is already been included:

```
function createProjectEventHandler(data){
    console.log('sth happened');
}
```

and click on button, then it just reloads the page. I don't see anything has been submitted back to managed bean and nothing on console.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

---

**Update**: it works with the following approach:

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{projectController.create}" 
    onevent="function(data) {console.log('aaa');}" render=":tblProject" />
```

Why is that so? Based on [the Java EE 6 tutorial on f:ajax events](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkddf.html), the `onevent` attribute should support a JavaScript function name.

Comment: Cause for some reason your js file isn't really included (wrong path? / wrong template?)

Comment: It's there, I can see with firebug it has been loaded.

Comment: I have never seen this problem. What JSF2 impl/version are you using?

Comment: can your js function `createProjectEventHandler` be called form browser console ?

Comment: BalusC:jsf2, Daniel: it works if I directly call it on console.

Comment: I was asking for the JSF2 implementation name and its version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.1.14" or "MyFaces 2.1.9". What you're stating is just the general JSF specification version. By the way, when there are multiple commenters on a post, use `@nickname` format with the `@` prefix to trigger comment reply notifications. Otherwise you're dependent on the eagerness of the commenter to manually review previously posted comments.

Comment: @BalusC it's Mojarra 2.1.7

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in Netbeans.

When I created my JSF page in Netbeans, it generated `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"` as XML namespace URI. But that was JSF 2.2 specific while I was actually using JSF 2.0/2.1.

When I changed the XML namespace URI to `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`, then it worked for me.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Where did netbeans imported the wrong library, why is it wrong? Mention JSF versions you used...

Comment: This doesn't answer the concrete question. In OP's case, the `<f:ajax>` works fine until the `onevent` attribute was added. In your particular case, the `<f:ajax>` (and all other `<f:xxx>` tags) simply doesn't work altogether.

Comment: i used apache myfaces JSF 2.2 Core API -> version 2.2.8.